# Can brand new hardware wallet have seed phrase initiated via sparrow? Or do is it need to be through wallet OEMs site only?

Tags: seed, hardware-wallet, sparrow-wallet, jade

Pretty straightforward. Can I initialize/generate seed phrase of blockstream jade via sparrow? Or do I need to go through blockstream's site to do this?